# When using beeware build android It gives "can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: python, android, beeware

When using beeware build android  It gives "can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"
I really do not know what wrong I am doing here. Below is the standard code from beeware sample app.  When I run this app it runs properly in the windows environment but when I try to deploy on android through the beeware command i.e. "**beeware build android**" I get the error "**can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**". Any ideas any one for me to try.

```
import toga


def button_handler(widget):
    print("hello")


def build(app):
    box = toga.Box()

button = toga.Button('Hello world', on_press=button_handler)
button.style.padding = 50
button.style.flex = 1
box.add(button)

return box


def main():
    return toga.App('First App', 'org.beeware.helloworld', startup=build)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main().main_loop()
```

Comment: Just to exclude two (unlikely?) causes. DID you do "briefcase CREATE android" prior to "build android" ? ... AND: you said you wrote "BEEWARE build ..." -- should it not be "BRIEFCASE build ..." ?

Comment: Thanks for the update, I gave up on Beeware and started using flutter.